# AddError messages don't appear

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, twig

I have a problem with implementing a form to upload files.
Uploading works fine, but there seems to be something wrong with checking the extension of the uploaded files and adding the error to the form.

This is my controller:

```
public function add(Application $app) {

    // Build the form
    $addform = $app['form.factory']
            ->createNamed('addform', 'form')
            ->add('title', 'text', array(
                'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\Length(array('min' => 5)))
            ))
            ->add('content', 'textarea', array(
                'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank())
            ))
            ->add('images', 'file', array(
                'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank())
            ));

    // Check file extension. If it's invalid, we'll manually add an error the form so that isValid() ends up returning false later one
        $files = $app['request']->files->get($addform->getName());

        if ($files['images'][0] !== null) {
            foreach ($files['images'] as $image) {
                if('.jpg' !== substr($image->getClientOriginalName(), -4)) {
                    $addform->get('images')->addError(new \Symfony\Component\Form\FormError('Only .jpg allowed'));
                }
            }
        }

    // Form was submitted: process it
    $addform->handleRequest($app['request']);


    // Form is valid
    if ($addform->isValid()) {

        // Add blogpost to database and save images

    }

    // Render the template with the form
    return $app['twig']->render('admin/blog/add.twig', array(
        'user' => $app['session']->get('user'),
        'addform' => $addform->createView()
    ));

}
```

And the part to upload images in my twig file looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(addform.images) }}
    {{ form_widget(addform.images, { 'full_name': addform.images.vars.full_name ~ '[]', 'attr' : { 'multiple': 'multiple' }} ) }}
    {{ form_errors(addform.images) }}
</div>
```

I seriously don't get what I'm doing wrong.
I did a var_dump of addform->get['images'] and the error was definitely in there, but when I try a dump of addform.images in my twigfile, there's no sign of the error. So ofcourse it won't display the error.

Another problem I'm having is that the form is still valid after the error is added. So I guess adding an error manually doesn't make a form invalid?

Comment: Try moving `->handleRequest` to before adding the error.

Comment: what happen if you try adding 'error_bubbling' , like  ->add('images', 'file', array(
                'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank()),'error_bubbling' => true
            ));

Comment: Thanks @Flosculus ! Moving the handleRequest did the trick.